# In C#, how use SQL to check for existing data in database?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2007

I'm working in c# and using sql commands to get, add, change data in a Access db. What I would like to do is check a table in the db for specific data, or record. I would need the command to return a value (true/false, 0/1) that will indicate if the data exist or not. My overall goal is to be able to run this check and if the data exist, then do nothing. If the data doesn't exist, then create it. Does anyone know how to do this. I assume there is a way to do this with sql, but I could be wrong. That's about it. I hope I presented my problem and question properly.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand you, just do a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ....`, if nothing is returned you know the data doesn't exist in the first place? Also worth noting if your table has a primary key and you are inserting a duplicate one, it will error anyway.

Comment: I didn't think about the COUNT() idea. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I would take would be to get all of rows with matching data.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM yourTable
 WHERE 
      yourTable.field1=value1
      AND 
      yourTable.field2=value2
```

From that point you could simply say if there are any records, do not add the new record.

```
 //we will assume the dt is a DataTable containing the data retrieved from the query
 if(dt.rows.count==0)
 {  
      //add the record
 }
```

If you prefer to use COUNT in SQL you could select the number of records

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM yourTable
 WHERE 
 yourTable.field1=value1
 AND 
 yourTable.field2=value2
```

And use ExecuteScalar (Selects the first column of the first row returned)

```
 //cmd is a command object that is set up to query your database
 try
 {
       int count=Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

       if(count==0)
       {
          //add the record
       }
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
    //do something with the error
 }
```

Comment: When it comes to getting the data into the DataTable, see Derek's answer.

Comment: This is the way I'm trying now.

Comment: I had to fix an error that was in here. I was using COUNT(), but COUNT() will always return 1 record (containing the number of records). What I did this time was to select all of the data with the conditions and count the number of rows.

Comment: If you want to use COUNT() I added the correct way to do that.

Comment: Please mark as the answer if this worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn OledbConnection, with Data Adapters, Commands and SQL Search Strings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452(v=vs.71).aspx

** EDIT ** 
You could create a private boolean method like this:-

```
Private Bool RecordMatch()
{
 // Perform SQL Search On Data Here, using Data Adapter and populating DataTable.
 // If DataTable is null reference return false
 // Else Return True

}
```

Comment: I would have known that, had you supplied code.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a simple SELECT query including a WHERE clause consisting of unique value corresponding to each added item and depending upon that you can have a check.

Comment: I was thinking about this way.

Comment: If you think so then just do it, all the best :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach statement, where you check all rows in table, if row is equal wanted row, than return true, else return false...

Comment: This would WORK, but it would not be fast (at lease on a large scale...imagine having to look at a 50,000 row this way...yikes!)